# error con Fiona GDAL y Geopandas "A GDAL API version must be specified"

Tags: python, pip

Quiero instalar fiona manualmente, he descargado, abierto el archivo y cuando corro el comando "python setup.py install", en la terminal en mi computadora me sale el siguiente código:

```
A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
```

La documentación está en  https://pypi.org/project/Fiona/#files, quiero usar geopandas por ello necesito instalar fiona.

¿Qué puede estar fallando?

Comment: No entiendo por qué esta pregunta tiene un voto negativo...

Comment: No lo se, uno a veces publica una pregunta es por que esta en problemas con la programación

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un problema que suele dar con Geopandas, ya que necesitas tener correctamente instaladas todos los paquetes que necesita. En **concreto GDAL (Geospatial Data Abstraction Library)** es una librería de representación de datos vectoriales en el espacio.

Lo más seguro es que tengas alguno de sus paquetes o sub-paquetes mal instalado, a mí también me paso en su día, y seguí la siguiente solución:

```
pip install wheel
pip install pipwin

pipwin install numpy
pipwin install pandas
pipwin install shapely
pipwin install gdal
pipwin install fiona
pipwin install pyproj
pipwin install six
pipwin install rtree
pipwin install geopandas
```

**pipwin** es una herramienta complementaria de **pip** que sirve para instalar paquetes no oficiales de Python.

**Si esta solución no te funciona**, utiliza `pip uninstall` con todos los paquetes y vuelve a instalar de nuevo.

Comment: Trato de instalar los paquetes y aun no puedp

Comment: Trato de instalar los paquetes y aun no puedp

Comment: ¿Te ha funcionado al final? En el caso de que no, ¿Qué problema te ha ocurrido?

Answer (score 1):

Lo pude ejecutar de inicio a fin! al final le hice un

```
pip3 install geopandas
```

y no me generó más errores.